# Could combinatorics questions have an easier approach

Tags: combinatorics

Recently I went through this question.

> There are five different rings. They are to be placed in the four fingers of a person. In how many ways can we do do?

The solution which our teacher gave was quite intuitive. He asked us to draw the four fingers and then observe that as we add rings the number of possible places for the next ring increases by one. Hence the answer is $4×5×6×7×8$. But this answer look quite familier. It is $^{9}P_{5}$. Later I found that it could be done by changing the question a bit which will convert it into a typical stars and bars problem. Similarly I also came through many such questions which could be done in more mathematical way by either changing the question or thinking it in some other way. So my question is that is the same possible for every such question. I  mean there are many questions in which we have to make cases. Can they too be solved by changing the question ? If yes , then how to decide which method to solve a question ?
Note: I am preparing for competitive exams where time is very important.

Comment: Your teacher used the rising factorial.  Another way to do this problem quickly is to arrange five different rings and three identical dividers (the jumps from one finger to the next).  Choose three of the eight positions for the dividers, then arrange the five different rings in the remaining five positions, which can be done in $\binom{8}{3} \cdot 5! = \frac{8!}{3!} = 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems which can be reformulated in such a way that they become easier to solve, particularly in combinatorics. However, unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately - we wouldn't want mathematics to be a bag of tricks to learn by heart), there is no general rule as to how to transform any given problem to make it easier, or even whether this is possible.

Certainly in exam situations I would expect that there is often an easy way to solve a problem if you look at it in the right way. (Anytime you find yourself doing a large case analysis you should rethink your approach.) But I'm afraid that the only way to improve here is to practice many problems and gain experience.